# The proof of $c_1(H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*))=\tilde{H}^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Here $X$ is a complex manifold. The proof below is from Wells'book p.106. I have a question about the claim that to see $\delta(H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*))=H^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, it suffices to show that the image of $H^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})$ is zero.

By the exactness of (4.7) (attached at last), we know $\delta(H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*))=ker(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}))$, but the image of $H^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ in $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})$ is zero only shows $H^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})\subset ker(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}))$, I wonder why it proves that $\delta(H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*))=H^2_{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe it follows from discussion on previous pages where chern forms have been written out explicitly as (1,1) forms, thus proving the image of the chern class map is contained in the (1,1) cohomology.

Comment: @roysmith thanks, but he didn’t mention that